# using should / had / would in place of "if" to connect sentense

Tags: grammar, should, would

I have seen this kind of construction many times. I sorta know what it means, but not really sure of what kind of grammar is it.

For example:

> And at the very least Gove has given a set of arguments to those in the party who would fight against grammars **should** there be a proposal to reintroduce them.
>
> The reddit wallet, **should** it have existed, had absolutely enormous potential.
>
> @wikileaks **had** there be no shysters , Assange would have been a common man and the same amount would have fed a lot poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, 'grammars' in your first sentence is short for 'grammar schools' - a kind of high school in the UK.  [Even in the UK, the shortening sounds odd to me, like calling high schools 'highs'.]  The 'should' is a way of forming a conditional clause, so could be re-written as " ... would fight against grammars if there had been a proposal ...".  Likewise, your second sentence means "The reddit wallet, if it had existed, ..." and your third "If there had been no shysters, Assange ..."

Comment: thanks. Found a more explanation here: http://www.englishpedia.net/my-grammar/advanced/if-clauses/reduction-of-if.html .